# gevent and requests - do they work togeather?

Tags: python, gevent

It it true that gevent does not work with requests library?  What is as of late best practice to fetch urls with gevent?  Is urllib2 still the lib to use?  I see that grequests has not been updated for over a year.

Thanks

Comment: You can use eventlet instead of gevent and if you want asynchronous requests as grequests not being updated regularly and do not catch exceptions you can use erequests(eventlet+requests).

Comment: Though it is not that gevent and requests don't work together. ;-)